# Growth Hormone and diabetes

Tags: endocrinology, pathology, experimental, diabetes-mellitus

Growth hormone and insulin like growth factors are diabetogenic, so I assume that people with high growth hormone (say due to pituitary tumor) may be at high risk for diabetes.  Has any correlation been established between these two? I know that diabetes is a multifactorial disorder and so only a correlation may be established.

Comment: Which type of diabetes mellitus are you interested in? Or both?

Comment: @leonardo I think this should not affect diabetes type 1 as dt1 is a mostly autoimmune disorder. So if some papers are available on this, I think, they would mostly be on type 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3053958):

> That GH has an effect on glycaemic control is most evident from the abnormal glucose tolerance seen in acromegalics...

`acromegaly` is defined as `abnormal growth of the hands, feet, and face, caused by overproduction of growth hormone by the pituitary gland.`

Such an effect has been [known for decades](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8300053), which makes sense given how interrelated the axes are.  Although I think the best evidence is the fact that the [side effects of growth hormone therapy](http://www.genotropin.com/) says that `Some patients have developed diabetes mellitus...`